# page will not refresh after a jQuery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a button call this script, so it does the post in the background, but I need to reload the current page to display an updated php query, I realize there was probably a better way in jquery to the query part, but its crunch time, and all I want to do is get a successful page refresh.
Because the buttons were generated in php, the javascript code is at the end of the body.
I've tried `location.href`, `window.location.reload(true);`, `document.write` which only wrote to the page, `document.location.href` did nothing.

We are using jQuery/jQuery mobile, I was not on front end dev team, so I'm desperate to get this to work. to clarify, I need a page refresh after the `$.post()` command, within this code, which does work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reserveBook').click(function () {
  var isbn = sessionStorage.getItem('isbn');
  $.post(
    "../inventory/postpage.php",
    { isbn: isbn }
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Another approach would be to use AJAX and update the information on the current page dynamically.

Comment: Posting the form to the page it is on without any javascript might be the simplest of all solutions.

Comment: Where did you include the reload function?

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in using AJAX if you need a page refresh regardless. As Dan Bracuk said in his comment, you'd be better off just doing a traditional form submission.

However, if you're set on having the page refresh, just add `window.location.reload()` in the success handler for your AJAX call:

```
$.post(
   "../inventory/postpage.php",
   { isbn: isbn },
   function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
   }

);
```